# Makefile link static library

Tags: makefile, hyperlink

just a simply makefile here, but always ld: linking error on static library linking 
the folder tree

```
├── include
│   └──main.h
├── lib
│   └── libmyrand.a
├── main.c
├── main.o
└──  Makefile
```

```
  1 TARGET= main
  2 
  3 INC = -Iinclude
  4 
  5 LIBDIR = ./lib
  6 LIB = libmyrand
  7 
  8 OBJS = main.o
  9 
 10 SOURCES = main.c
 11 
 12 
 13 all: $(TARGET)
 14 
 15 $(TARGET): $(OBJS)
 16   gcc -o main  $< -L$(LIBDIR) -l$(LIB)
 17 
 18 $(OBJS):  $(SOURCES)
 19   gcc -c -g $(INC)  $< 
 20 
 21 .PHONY: clean
 22 
 23 clean:
 24   rm -f *.o
```

make error message:

```
gcc -c -g -Iinclude  main.c 
gcc -o main -L./lib -llibmyrand main.o 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmyrand
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:16: main] Error 1
```

---

if i change the line #15-#16 to

```
 15$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
 16   gcc -o main  $< ./lib/libmyrand.a
```

make done!
balabala

Comment: your error message doesn't match what would be produced in by the makefile-- `gcc -o main -L./lib -lmyrand main.o #./lib/rand.a` -- in your recipe the objects appear before the `-L` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a makefile problem.  This is a misunderstanding of how the compiler and linker work.  If you typed the original command at your shell prompt, not via make, then it would fail the same way.  So, you know it doesn't have anything to do with make.

The compiler command line `-lfoo` option will always look for libraries name `libfoo.so` or `libfoo.a`.  So if you want to use `-lmyrand`, then you need to name your library `libmyrand.so` or `libmyrand.a`.

`.a` is static libraries and `.so` is shared libraries, of course, so if you are using static libraries you want `libmyrand.a`.

Comment: Thanks for response first .  but...still not luck...... the "can not find  -llibmyrand " error still at there. after i named myrand.a to libmyrand.a

Comment: What is the name of your library, exactly?  If it's `libmyrand.a`, then you need to use `-lmyrand` not `-llibmyrand`.  If you use `-llibmyrand` then the linker will look for `liblibmyrand.a`.